# How can I execute a delete query in mysql using onclick javascript function in php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I am using php and inside php page a list comes with a delete button in front of every record, as i click on the delete button the single record should be deleted with the help of javascript onclick function. 
Is it possible to execute a delete query in script tag type javascript. please help.

Comment: We need see some code, what have you tried?

Comment: Yes it's possible. You can make asynchronous calls via javascript to reach out and do your deletes. Are you familiar with any javascript libraries?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX to fire the entry's ID to a php script that deletes a record based on the ID it received from the AJAX -